# Sensitivity Analysis: Python package to estimate specific higher order Sobol indices

Tags: python, data-analysis, statistics

I would like to know if a python package exists that estimates specific Sobol indices, namely those that are higher than 2nd order. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance-based_sensitivity_analysis) for variance-based sensitivity analysis is quite good for understanding the Sobol method / indices.

For example, given a model with 10 parameters, what are the *S*<sub>ijk</sub> and *S*<sub>mnop</sub> third and fourth order indices respectively?

I am keenly aware that the number of model evaluations needed to calculate all higher order indices is 2<sup>d</sup> - 1; however, I am only interested in less than ten specific indices.

If no python package exists, please recommend some other software.